# Python Django маршрутизация routing

Tags: python, django, маршрутизация

Есть urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', index),
path('<slug:cat_id>/', sneaker_cat, name = 'sneaker_cat'),
path('<slug:url_sneaker_model>/', sneaker_menu, name = 'sneaker_menu'),]
```

На данный момент при переходе с sneaker_cat на sneaker_menu появляется исключение - вместо cat_id был получен url_sneaker_model. При этом в url браузера id заменяется на модель кроссовки. Проблему можно решить добавлением / перед slug:url_sneaker_model/, но в таком случае юрл будет например: http://127.0.0.1:1000/sneakers//Nike_Air_Monarch_IV/ (две //).

Вопрос, как сделать так что бы юрл был например таким: http://127.0.0.1:1000/sneakers/1/Nike_Air_Monarch_IV/.
Тут 1 после sneakers - cat_id. Мне нужно что бы 1 оставался в юрл при переходе с sneaker_cat на sneaker_menu

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
    path('<slug:cat_id>/', sneaker_cat, name='sneaker_cat'),
    path('<slug:cat_id>/<slug:url_sneaker_model>/', sneaker_menu, name='sneaker_menu'),
]
```

Вариант 2.

```
from django.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
    path('<slug:cat_id>/', include([
        path('', sneaker_cat, name='sneaker_cat'),
        path('<slug:url_sneaker_model>/', sneaker_menu, name='sneaker_menu'),
    ]),
]
```

Пример с оффициальной документации тут – [ссылка](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#example).